# How to format a text input as a decimal in jquery

Tags: jquery, decimal

I have this jQuery code:

```
$('#amount').change(function() {
  $('#amount').val( $('#amount').val().toFixed(2) );
}); // end .change()
```

I need it to format the input in decmial format. Can it be done in jquery?

Example:
In a text box,

if I enter `5` I want the value to be shown as `5.00`

if I enter `5.1` I want the value to be shown as `5.10`

if I enter `5.12` I want the value to be shown as `5.12`

seems to be a simple need. I have to be missing something because I cannot imagine that javascript or jquery does not provide a function to do this.

Comment: decimal format how exactly, could you give some examples of input and output ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An elements value is always a string, and `toFixed` only works on numbers, so you have to convert the value to a number before you run `toFixed` on it

```
$('#amount').on('change', function() {
    this.value = parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZC387/10/)

Comment: thanks @adeneo. I was going down that same path. glad you confirmed I was thinking along the proper lines. appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Use this as the base:

```
Math.round(num * 100) / 100
```

So your code will be:

```
$('#amount').change(function() {
    $('#amount').val( Math.round($('#amount').val() * 100) / 100 );
});
```

Comment: @H.Ferrence Sure, waiting.. :D

Comment: well it did not work in my script @PraveenKumar I entered `5` and got `5`

Comment: this works: `$('#amount').val('5.25');` so I at least proved to myself the onChange() is working.

Comment: @H.Ferrence - `(5 * 100) / 100` still equals 5, so this only works with something like `5.222222` which would give `5.22` etc. but this is generally where `toFixed` comes in, but you're already using that, and you still seem to have a problem, it's just not clear what the problem is ?

Comment: the problem @adeneo is that when I enter `5` in the textbox I expect to get `5.00` but I am only getting `5` -- that's the problem.

Comment: @H.Ferrence - Oh, now I see, you're using the value directly, and that's a string, not a number, it should be like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZC387/8/